# Unable to use IntEnum as tkinter.IntVar

Tags: tkinter

I'd like to use `IntEnum` to populate a tk `IntVar` (It's not a requirement, but I'd like to). But calls to `get()` fail (see below). I believe this is a `tkinter` bug, but maybe I'm assuming something that I shouldn't be. Mostly looking for confirmation here ATM.

`IntEnum` is formally a subclass of `int`, so I'd expect to be able to do anything with it that I could do with an `int`.

I am using python 3.6.

example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from enum import IntEnum

class Example(IntEnum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2

# These conversions to int and float work fine
print(int(Example.ONE))
print(float(Example.TWO))

app = tk.Tk() # needed to initialize something-or-other, else IntVar construction fails

var = tk.IntVar()

# Setting the value works fine
var.set(Example.ONE)
print('set succeeded')
print()

# Getting the value raises exceptions
x = var.get()
print(f'get result: {x}')
```

Output:

```
1
2.0
set succeeded

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 508, in get
    return self._tk.getint(value)
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "Example.ONE"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../scratch.py", line 65, in <module>
    x = var.get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 510, in get
    return int(self._tk.getdouble(value))
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "Example.ONE"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no bug: `Enum` members are of `type` of the `enum` (which is the reason for enums in the first place); `tk.IntVar` requires an `int` type (which is the reason for IntVars).

You can use `var.set(Example.ONE.value)`

```py
from enum import IntEnum

class Example(IntEnum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2

# These conversions to int and float work fine
print(int(Example.ONE))
print(float(Example.TWO))

app = tk.Tk() # needed to initialize something-or-other, else IntVar construction fails

var = tk.IntVar()

var.set(Example.ONE.value)    # <--- set IntVar value with a proper int
print('set succeeded')
print()

# Getting the value is now okay
x = var.get()
print(f'get result: {x}')
```

**Output:**

```
1
2.0
set succeeded

get result: 1
```

Comment: (sorry, code formatting not working below)
Thank you for pointing out the `value` member. I guess the part I am struggling with here is that `IntEnum` **is** an `int` (as shown by MRO hierarchy), so any operation that can be applied to an int should also be applicable to an IntEnum. If this isn't a bug, I will need to reexamine what inheritance "is-a" relation really means in Python...

`
>>> class Example(IntEnum):

...     ONE = 1

...     TWO = 2

... 

>>> Example.__mro__

(<enum 'Example'>, <enum 'IntEnum'>, <class 'int'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>)
`

Answer (score -1):

I've concluded this is a bug or at least a quite undesirable behavior in `IntEnum` but not a bug in `tkinter`: it just happens to be exposed by this specific `tkinter` use case. That bug is that `int(str(x))` fails even though `x` is an `int`. I am not accepting Reblochon Masque's answer because the condition "`tk.IntVar` requires an `int` type" is in fact formally met by the use of `IntEnum`.

Here is a simplified example:

```
>>> from enum import IntEnum
>>> 
>>> class Example(IntEnum):
...   ONE = 1
... 
>>> x = Example.ONE
>>> x.value
1
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
>>> str(x)
'Example.ONE'
>>> int(str(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Example.ONE'
```